# Velocity addition formula derived from velocity boosts

Tags: special-relativity, velocity, inertial-frames

I understand the derivation for the equation the velocity in a boosted frame by taking the boosts of the differentials such that: $v'^{\mu}= \frac{dx'^{\mu}}{dt'}
$ where $x^{\mu} = \Lambda^{\mu}_{\, \, \nu}x^{\nu}$ and then simply differenting w.r.t. $t$ to get for example a boost in x-direction by $u$ to get $v_{x}' = \frac{v_{x} - u}{1 - \frac{uv_{x}}{c^{2}}}$. However, why is it not simply possible to say that $v'^{\mu} = \Lambda^{\mu}_{\, \, \nu}v^{\nu}$. How is the first equation for velocity boosts derived from this equation?

Comment: Have you seen the derivation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula#Standard_configuration), under the heading *A proof using 4-vectors and Lorentz transformation matrices* ?

Comment: Thank you so much! had not seen that part. So the four velocity does not refer to the actual velocity measured? it is the ordinary velocity that is measured?

Comment: Yes, it's the ordinary velocity that is measured. The ordinary velocity is a normal 3D vector, the [4-velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity) also has a time-like zeroth component, and its magnitude is always $c$. Even more important is the [4-momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum).